# preparing a large file for downloading in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, background-process, django-channels

I use Django Rest Framework to serialize the data from my database, convert it to json and let user download it as a text file.

The problem is that it takes quite a bit of time for preparing the file, so the server timeout sometimes happens.

I switched to Django Channels in order to avoid the timeout, but now I do it in a rather ugly way: I send a signal to Channels, the serializer prepares the data, dumps it to a directory, and then sends back an url to download this temporary file. Everything works, but I have a bunch of temporary files, which I now need to clean regularly (with a cronjob).

Is there more 'right' way of preparing large file in background and pass it to a view for downloading without necessary storing it on disk?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an in-memory file with StringIO if the size is not large:

```
from io import StringIO
f = StringIO("some text data")
```